# Receive IDOC as an xmldocument without a schema

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, idoc

I have a business case where we need to receive an IDOC and transmit it as received. We don't have to care about version change or other things. Is it possible to do it without generating IDOC schema?

Comment: Any reason you want it as a xmldocument then?   As was suggested on the TechNet post, you could just use PassThru pipelines if all you are doing is receiving and sending it.  Which adapter are you using to receive it?

Comment: The adapter used is Wcf-sap

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

I'm 92% sure you could do this with the legacy SAP Adapter.  It just returned Xml like any other Adapter.  You then had to use the XmlDisassembler and such.

The WCF SAP Adapter/Binging...you'll have try.  The WCF Bindings in general are a bit more sensitive to schemas and such.